# How to source a .sh script on pip install with pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pip, autocomplete

I am trying to have TAB completion for a command line program `your_script.py` which is imported by `main_script.py`. [argcomplete](https://pypi.org/project/argcomplete/) is not working for me, so I am using bash [complete](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) (only has to work on a server with bash).

I have an `completion_script.sh`, when I source this the auto completion works when I directly run `./main_script.py`. However, I have trouble getting it to work for the command line tool after `pip install`.

I tried adding the below lines to `pyproject.toml`, but this did not work.

```
[tool.setuptools]
script-files = ["src/cmdline_test/completion_script.sh"]
```

How can I get `pyproject.toml` to source `completion_script.sh` correctly?

---

Working example, if you source `completion_script.sh` and make `main_script.py` executable, running with `./main_script.py TAB` will show autocomplete. Can `pip install .` in top directory, can then run `cmdline_test` (if install location is in PATH), but tab completion is not working.

Directory structure:

```
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── cmdline_test
        ├── completion_script.sh
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main_script.py
        └── your_script.py
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = "cmdline_test"
version = "0.0.1"

[project.scripts]
cmdline_test = "cmdline_test.main_script:main"

[tool.setuptools]
script-files = ["src/cmdline_test/completion_script.sh"]
```

`completion_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

_fruit_autocomplete() {
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local options=("apple" "banana" "cherry" "grape")
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${options[*]}" -- "$cur"))
}

_pos_autocomplete() {
    # Define possible values for the positional argument
    local _positional_argument_values=("test1" "test2")
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${_positional_argument_values[*]}" -- "$cur"))
}


_autocomplete() {
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    case "$prev" in
        *main_script.py)
            _pos_autocomplete
            ;;
        --fruit)
            _your_script_fruit_autocomplete
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
}

# also tried complete -F _autocomplete src/cmdline_test/main_script.py src/cmdline_test/your_script.py in case it needs path relative to pyproject.toml, but did not work
complete -F _autocomplete main_script.py your_script.py
```

`main_script.py`

```
from your_script import create_parser, main

def main():
    parser = create_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`your_script.py`

```
import argparse

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Your Script Example')
    parser.add_argument('--fruit', help='Choose a fruit', choices=['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grape''])
    parser.add_argument("pipeline_name", choices=['test1', 'test2'], help='Choose a pipeline')
    return parser
```